# ¿ Por qué persiste el error: MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Estoy usando **node/express** y cuando quiero hacer la peticion a **Mongodb** sale este error por consola:

```js
Connected succesfully to mongo
C:\ecommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:691
          throw error;
          ^

MongoError: MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db   
    at MongoClient.db (C:\ecommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:347:11)
    at C:\ecommerce\lib\mongo.js:27:29
    at C:\ecommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:688:9
    at C:\ecommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:257:23
    at C:\ecommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:283:21
    at parseConnectionString (C:\ecommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\uri_parser.js:611:12)
    at connect (C:\ecommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:281:3)
    at C:\ecommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:256:5
    at maybePromise (C:\ecommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:685:3)
    at MongoClient.connect (C:\ecommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:252:10)
```

Aca el codigo para conectar a **Mongodb**. buscando una solucion vi que muchos quitan  el número de puerto **(${config.port})** de la variable **MONGO_URI** pero tampoco me ah dado resultado.

archivo **mongo.js**

```js
// npm i -S mongodb para conecectar a mongodb
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const { config } = require("../config"); // Obtengo los datos de configuracion de la carpeta "config"

const USER = encodeURIComponent(config.dbUser);
const PASSWORD = encodeURIComponent(config.dbPassword);
const DB_NAME = config.dbName;

//const MONGO_URI = `mongodb://${USER}:${PASSWORD}@${config.dbHost}:${config.dbPort}/?authSource=${DB_NAME}`; // prettier-ignore
const MONGO_URI = `mongodb+srv://${USER}:${PASSWORD}@${config.dbHost}/${DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
class MongoLib {
  constructor() {
    // console.log('MONGO URI: ' + MONGO_URI);
    this.client = new MongoClient(MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
    this.dbName = DB_NAME;
  }

  connect() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.client.connect(error => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        }

        console.log("Connected succesfully to mongo");
        resolve(this.client.db(this.dbName));
      });
    });
  }

  getAll(collection, query) {
    return this.connect().then(db => {
      return db
        .collection(collection)
        .find(query)
        .toArray();
    });
  }
}

// Exporto la clase para que otros archivos puedan utilizarla
module.exports = MongoLib;
```

Answer (score 0):

Buscando encontré una solución que a mi me sirvió y espero que ayude a otros tambien:

Crei que el error solo estaba en mi archivo **"mongo.js"**, pero resulta que tambien tenia mal el host en mi archivo **".env"**
En mi caso el host lo sacaba de esta manera:

En **mongodb Atlas** copiaba el **host** de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ahi les va a aparecer un string parecido a este:
**mongodb+srv://blabla:@cluster0.xxxxx.mongodb.net/test**
yo copiaba todo el string, cuando en realidad era solo esto:
**cluster0.xxxxx.mongodb.net/test**

Entonces en mi archivo **.env** en la variable **DB_HOST** hice la corrección del string del host.

```js
// CONFIG
PORT=8000

// MONGO
DB_USER= xxxxx
DB_PASSWORD= xxxxxxx
DB_HOST=cluster0.xxxxx.mongodb.net/test 
DB_PORT=8000
DB_NAME=db_ecommerce
```